# access UDP port without doing port forwading

Tags: udp, port

I have developed a chat application with voice call. The voice call is working fine if it is connected locally (using local ip address). However, when I test it over the internet (using external/public ip address) it can send packets but not able to receive packets. The packets were sent through UDP. I was able to fix that through port forwarding.  We are about to distribute the apk to several people to test the application and I don't want to require each of them to do port forwarding just to make the voice call works. Now my question is, how can my program access the UDP port(any UDP port as long as it would work) without doing port forwarding? Just like Viber or any other program I have used, I did not open any ports on my router. It automatically work. How can I do that? Is there a code that I need to execute? Or do I have to register my application? Please help. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This is a complex issue, especially if both parties are behind a router/firewall. Look for STUN and TURN or into the RFC for ICE (RFC5254), that's how the usual SIP clients do it. There is probably at least one library out there which helps you with this stuff.

Comment: Kindly provide me more details like a link. I am just a student trying to complete my thesis and I don't know what and where to look. I've been searching for weeks now but I'm still unable to figure this out myself.

Comment: please just search online for STUN, TURN, ICE and RFC5254. There are also wikipedia articles about the topic.

Comment: I have read about UDP hole punching and I will test it tomorrow. I do have other questions though that I would like to clarify. Do I have to register the UDP port that I will be using to IANA? If yes, why? And what will happen if it's registered? Will that automatically unblock my application from using the UDP port? Is there like opened UDP ports that I can use? I've searched over he internet and I just couldn't find the answer to my questions.